# How to aggregate store calls

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I need to call one store two times with different parameter values. Is there any way to aggregate two different calls?

```
var result1 = myStore.load({params:{id:id1}}); ==> 3 results
var result2 = myStore.load({params:{id:id2}}); ==> 4 results
                                                   Total 7 results
```

Comment: I don't think you can aggregate calls. But you call it one after other using callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `addRecords: true` config option to your second and subsequent `load` params if you want to aggregate the records.

See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

But if you want to send both loading sequences as one request, you will have to modify your server's API to accept multiple IDs.